# HLS streaming on mobile device with flow player

Tags: video-streaming, flowplayer, nimble

I am facing problem with playing recorded video(with hls streaming using Nimble streamer) with flow player on mobile devices, it works fine with desktop but when we try it with mobile browser, it says video file not found, but it is there.

Please see demo you get more idea: http://1.22.229.11/flowplayer/flowplayer/test.html
File path is http://1.22.229.11:8081/videos/fast.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

Some mobile devices do not support HLS (like android version < 5.0 ).
File type mp4 is the most compatible with mobile devices I believe.